# How to copy a std::string to unsigned char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, type-conversion

How to copy a std::string (sample) to unsigned char array (trap)?

```
int main() {
    unsigned char trap[256];
    std::string sample = ".1.3.6.1.4";
    strcpy(trap,sample.c_str());
    std::cout << trap << std::endl;
}
```

**Above code throws error:**

```
time.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
time.cpp:20: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’
time.cpp:20: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
```

Comment: With `::memcpy()` or with a cast to `char*`.

Comment: short answer: you shouldn't do it. user `char` array instead.

Comment: Why is this what you want to do?

Comment: @YSC: Thanks , im using c++, so please write the cast line in above case?

Comment: @erip : i need to assign a std::string to unsigned char array

Comment: I know _what_ you need to do, I don't know _why_ you want to do it.

Comment: A situation were you might need sth like this if you have a std::string and want to send it over TCP sockets which excepts bytes (unsigned char).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int
{
    unsigned char trap[256];
    std::string sample = ".1.3.6.1.4";
    std::copy( sample.begin(), sample.end(), trap );
    trap[sample.length()] = 0;
    std::cout << trap << std::endl;
}
```

It can be a good idea to additionally check whether the buffer is sufficiently large.

Comment: `return` is missing.

Comment: -.- I was mislead by the trailing return type... and by my lazyness: not to double check...

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf :  Thanks a Lot !!

Comment: Just looking at this I realized that with a C++ implementation where `std::string` has raw pointers as iterators (unlikely but permitted), the unqualified call to `copy` would not invoke Argument Dependent Lookup and it would not be found. Fixed by adding namespace qualification.

Answer (score 3):

Using reinterpret_cast would also be possible:

```
int main() {
    std::string sample = ".1.3.6.1.4";
    auto uCharArr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(sample.c_str());
}
```